# What would be the best fitting site for Warcraft movie lore questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm going to watch the film and - as someone that doesn't know much about Warcraft's lore - there will be some questions that will arise from it. However I'm not sure where to ask them. While I assume this is the site where I have best chances to receive accurate feedback, it feels as if I had to ask it on movies or SFF SE, since it is originating from the movie and therefore has nothing to do with the game except sharing the universe.

So where would be the best for for Warcraft lore questions?

Comment: Lore questions are allowed here, but for whatever reason tend to be unpopular. You'd probably get a good reception and better answers on SF&F though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Questions directly about the feature film *Warcraft*, as well as the various novels and other material set in that universe, are **Off Topic**. Questions about the lore and story from the *Warcraft* video games - which is to say, *Warcraft*, *Warcraft II*, *Warcraft III*, and *World of Warcraft* - are, of course, on topic.

While information *from* these other tie-in materials may contain, and may be used to answer questions about video game lore, in general, we have not taken questions about tie-in material, regardless of it's similarity to the existing video game narrative.

There are several other SE sites where questions about the *Warcraft* movie would be welcome, including [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and [Movies and Television](https://movies.stackexchange.com/). The former would also tend to consider the various *Warcraft* novels on topic, *as well as* the narrative content of the various video games. (As you can see, there is overlap between several SE sites on a variety of topics. This is *normal and fine.*)

Comment: Are we 100% sure games are on-topic at SciFi? I only ask as that might make them a valid source for some of the "identify this game" questions we receive

Comment: Last I checked, they were, but I admittedly check in with SFF.SE very rarely.

Comment: @Timelord64 I've seen game lore questions accepted there before. I'll try to find some examples.

Comment: I'm not sure that the blanket statement in the first sentence is *entirely* accurate, but agree that these questions are a better fit for the other two sites. There may be some overlap and/or relationship between the movie story and game stories, which could lead to some of these questions being on-topic.